# JAVA: Iterating vertical object values in a collection to horizontal object values

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a list of an object with 3 items that accepts BookID, bookseries, and Format as shown below:

```
List<BookFormat> book= new ArrayList<BookFormat>();

book.add(1,A,A0);
book.add(1,A,A1);
book.add(1,A,A2);
book.add(2,B,A1);
book.add(2,B,A2);
book.add(3,C,A4);
book.add(4,D,A0);
book.add(4,D,A2);
book.add(4,D,A3);
```

Now I'm trying to sort it on the horizontal basis on the "BookID" on which I have created another new class object "BookFormatNew" that returns true or false if the specified "Format" is available or not.

```
class BookFormatNew{
      String BookID,
      String BookSeries,
      String A0,
      String A1,
      String A2,
      String A3,
      String A4}
```

where A0, A1, A2, A3, and A4 takes up "T" if the value is available or "F" if not.

The expected output result should be something like this

```
List<BookFormatNew> bookNew= new ArrayList<BookFormatNew>();

bookNew.add(1,A,T,T,T,F,F);
bookNew.add(2,B,F,T,T,F,F);
bookNew.add(3,C,F,F,F,F,T);
bookNew.add(4,D,T,F,T,T,F);
```

How to iterate the vertical values for the BookFormat in order to get an output which is the NewBookFormat as horizontal values?

Thanks for taking out your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Map while iterating vertical list.

```
HashMap<Integer, BookFormatNew> map = new HashMap<>();
for(BookFormat b: book){
    BookFormatNew bfn = map.get(b.getBookId());
    if(bfn == null){
        // Create new EntryPair and add
        BookFormatNew bfn_new = new BookFormatNew(b.getBookId(), b.getBookSeries(), "F","F","F","F","F");
        map.put(b.getBookId(), bfn_new);
        bfn = map.get(b.getBookId());
    }
    if(b.getFormat().equals("A0"){
        bfn.setA0("T");
    }
    else if(b.getFormat().equals("A1"){
        bfn.setA1("T");
    }
    else if(b.getFormat().equals("A2"){
        bfn.setA2("T"); 
    }
    else if(b.getFormat().equals("A3"){
        bfn.setA3("T");
    }
    else if(b.getFormat().equals("A4"){
        bfn.setA4("T");
    }

    map.put(b.getBookId(),bfn);  // Puts updated T,F set
}
```

Then iterate through the map and add it to new horizontal list if necessary or use the map itself.

Comment: What is bfn_new here?

Comment: New BookFormatNew Object. Since corresponding BookFormatNew doesn't exist yet in Map, create one and put it to map.

Comment: How do you create one?

Comment: I have updated answer with complete code. That gives you required hashmap

Comment: Is this line "map.add(b.getBookId(), bfn_new);" supposed to be "map.put(b.getBookId(), bfn_new);"as HashMap doesnt have .add?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Typo

Comment: im getting a null pointer exception at line "bfn.setA0("T");"

Comment: Thanks a lot for saving the day...i found the error and its working fine.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you. Glad its working

Comment: I accepted it but I cant upvote as my reputations are below the accepted value.

Comment: No problem . Thanks